# how to call an open powerpoint from excel vba

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I am trying to open a ppt from a given location, and trying to break all the links in the ppt. Once the ppt is opened, I am not able to call the ppt from excel from there onwards and hence the code is giving error. The line that gives me error is the following - "For Each Sld In ActiveWindow.Slides" - the object doesn't support this property or method. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub Breaklinks()

Dim file As String
Dim PPT As Object
Dim Sld As Slide
Dim Sh As Shape

file = Cells(4, 2).Value & "\" & Cells(4, 3).Value

Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPT.Visible = True
PPT.Presentations.Open file

For Each Sld In ActiveWindow.Slides
    For Each Sh In Sld.Shapes
        If Sh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            Sh.LinkFormat.BreakLink
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're in Excel, which doesn't have an ActiveWindow.Slides property.

Try it this way:

```
' At the beginning:
Dim oPres as Presentation

' Then instead of this:
' PPT.Presentations.Open file
' do this
Set oPres = PPT.Presentations.Open file

' then ...
For Each Sld In oPres.Slides
    For Each Sh In Sld.Shapes
        If Sh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            Sh.LinkFormat.BreakLink
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for the reply. When I write the statement you mentioned "Set Pres = PPT.Presentations.Open file". I get error : "Expected : end of statement". Sorry in case i misunderstood your explanation.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Should be Set oPres=PPT.Presentations.Open(file)

Comment: Hey Steve, looks like we are really close to fixing this. This time the following code is giving me trouble - "For Each Sh In Sld.Shapes", it says - "Run time error 13, type mismatch". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure about that; it seems ok to me.  The next line might through wobblies though.  Change it to If Sh.Type = 10 Then  (10 is the value of msoLinkedOLEObject, which may not be defined in Excel)

Comment: Got it........ I was using the variable Sh as Shape, when I used this variable Sh as object instead of shape, it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, of course.  Excel has shapes too.  Assuming you've set a reference to PowerPoint, you could Dim Sh as PowerPoint.Shape and get the benefit of intellisense.